# How to search in elastic search with separated by space and without space

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

My Query is below

- I am searching for `L1 L2` in the elastic search cluster with some aggregation function
- I am converting `L1 L2` to **L1* OR *L2**

Requirement

- I need to search on `L1 L2` first (high weigtage)
- Then I need to search on `L1` and `L2` separately.

My Template is below need to update in `'query': '**L1* OR *L2**`

```
template =  {
  'from': 0,
  'size': 10,
  'aggs': {
    'Tester': {
      'terms': {
        'field': 'Tester.name.keyword',
        'order': {
          '_key': 'desc'
        }
      }
    },
    'Developer': {
      'terms': {
        'field': 'Developer.name.keyword',
        'order': {
          '_key': 'desc'
        }
      }
    },
    'Analyst': {
      'terms': {
        'field': 'Analyst.name.keyword',
        'order': {
          '_key': 'desc'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must': {
        'query_string': {
          'query': '**L1* OR *L2**'
        }
      },
      'filter': {
        'term': {
          'parentName.keyword': 'Software Department'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there way to achieve without change in settings

Comment: You need shingles to improve the multi term relevance. Don't have time to add full answer.

Comment: @DavidVdd is there any way to achieve with out change the settings

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @David in the comment, you can use the [shingles token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) to achieve your use-case.

**Adding a working example, which clearly shows the higher score for docs conatining `L1 L2` while `L1` and `L2` docs also coming in search results.**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                    "filter": [
                        "shingle"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "name" : "L1 L2"
}

{
    "name" : "L1"
}
{
    "name" : "L2"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "L1 L2"
        }
    }
}
```

**And search response**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "shingleside",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0462961,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "L1 L2"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "shingleside",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.5619608,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "L1"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "shingleside",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.5619608,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "L2"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: is there any way to do without change the settings

Comment: @sim sorry for delay in response, no there is no other way of doing this without changing the analyzer, as index time tokens needs to be present in the format, which matches your search terms.